# How do I vertical center a label in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with a height of `30px`.

I want to add plain text to this `div`. How can I make the plain text appear on the center of my div?
i.e, the text will be shown `15px` under the top of the `div`.

I tried a label with `margin-top: 15;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 28):

```
height: 30px; line-height: 30px; padding: 0;
```

Answer (score 16):

Following CSS would work

```
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle; 
display:table-cell;
```

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat worked in IE8, which IE specifically does this not work in?

Comment: @MyName this answer was originally posted **3 years ago**, when IE6 and IE7 still had large market share. So now it should actually be okay to use.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat Ahh I'm sorry I should have read the date this was posted. But that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can:

```
<div style="height:30px; line-height:30px; text-align:center;">
    Label
</div>
```

Set the `line-height` of the text helps you to fit the height for one line only.

Comment: Adding line-height to my div style solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

Although this is an old thread, I think a `flex` solution should also be presented.
If you style your div with

```
display: flex; 
align-items: center;
```

it should work

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-paper-c9tlc)

Answer (score 1):

Use padding-top instead of margin-top. Remember that adding padding to the top is added to the height, so you need to reduce the amount that you use for padding from the height. If you just always want for the text to have 15px on top and bottom of it, just simply do:

```
padding: 15px 0px;
```

Without specifying height at all.

Comment: I think the asker wants it to be 30px, text height inclusive.

Comment: pesky time dealing with styling this contact form, your suggestion resolved it, thx!!

Answer (score 0):

padding-top: 15px;

remove 15px from the height on the div to.

you should have a look at padding http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: you are forgetting the height of the text to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want anything to be in center of it's parent, just give the parent specific width using style and give the child style="margin:0 auto".
good luck

Comment: Horizontal and non-IE6, yes. But the question was about vertical positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The `<label></label>` Element is not a block level element it is an inline element.

Try this code
 `<div style="height:30px">
<label style="display:block; margin-top:15px;">
</label>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

```
#MyDiv
{ 
    background-image: url(images/pagedescription_bar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #868686;
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: solid;
    border-style: none;
    width: 1008px;
    height:70px;
    color: #FB8022;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#MyDiv label
{
    width: 1008px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```